# Export the visible area of canvas in high resolution

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs

I am working on an html5 canvas for this I am using konvajs and anglurjs. I want to export the visible area of canvas with the higher resolutions.

I am able to export the visible area by using **stage.toDataURL('JPEG',1.0)** but it regrades the resolution of the image. It sets the image dimensions according the browser window but I want to export the image in the same resolution as I imported.

Answer (score 5):

There is an undocumented config for `stage.toDataURL()` called `pixelRatio`:

```
stage.toDataURL({ pixelRatio: 2})
```

This command will save the canvas with higher resolution.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/quveduhihe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks @Iavrton for the response. I tried this as well but it decreases the image quality.